# Find an element in an infinite length sorted array

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Given an infinite length sorted array having both positive and negative integers. Find an element in it.

**EDIT**
All the elements in the array are unique and the array in infinite in right direction.

There are two approaches:

## Approach 1:

Set the index at position 100, if the element to be found is less, binary search in the previous 100 items, else set the next index at position 200. In this way, keep on increasing the index by 100 until the item is greater.

## Approach 2:

Set the index in power of 2. First set the index at position 2, then 4, then 8, then 16 and so on. Again do the binary search from position 2^K to 2^(K + 1) where item is in between.

Which of the two approaches will be better both in best case and worst case?

Comment: What does "better" mean when you're dealing with an infinite collection? What sort of asymptotics are you after? Is the array infinite in both directions, or does it have a smallest element? Are the elements unique?

Comment: Given truly infinite length, it makes no difference -- neither one has any hope of successfully finding an element, except by accident. No matter how you search, the percentage of the array you're able to search is some finite number N / infinity = 0% of the array.

Comment: The starting point of the array is known thus making it infinite in right direction.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I disagree. The array itself is infinite, but every element in it has a final number of elements before it.

Comment: @amit: You can talk meaningfully about behavior as the length *approaches* infinity, but not about when it truly *is* infinite. When you try to deal with infinity instead of just "as x approaches infinity", nearly everything falls apart. Nonetheless, you do have something of a point: the rephrasing to say it extends in only one direction probably makes it at least theoretically possible to find some elements.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Even if the array is truly infinite - even a simple linear scan over it will find if `x` exists for each `x` in final amount of time (assuming sorted and no dupes, of course). Thus, I think this "amount of time" is something worth discussion.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Also note, even if the array is infinite to both sides, it can be easily reduced to one sided infinite array: access an arbitrary index (let it be `k`). if `x < arr[k]` : Search in one sided infinite array where indexes are `(-infninity,k]`. Otherwise, search in `[k,infinity)`. The only issues are really uniqueness and non-zeno property (which is guaranteed for integers)

Comment: @amit: (Sorry, had to disappear to take kids to school). The first time I read the rewritten question, I didn't notice that he'd also added a uniqueness constraint. With that it becomes trivial. The maximum index for a value N is `N-X[0]`, and from there a normal binary search (or whatever) becomes the "right" answer.

Comment: If it helps avoid boggling anybody's mind, maybe replace "infinite sorted array of unique values" with "monotonic increasing function of the natural numbers, computed by a constant-time oracle."

Comment: Do you want to include in the time complexity calculations that math on the indexes takes more than O(1) time?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first approach will be linear in the index of the element (`O(k)` where `k` is the index of the element). Actually, you are going to need `k/100` iterations to find the element which is greater than the searched element, which is `O(k)`.

The second approach will be logarithmic in the same index. `O(logk)`. (where `k` is the index of the element). In here, you are going to need `log(k)` iterations until you find the higher element. Then binary search between `2^(i-1)`, `2^i` (where `i` is the iteration number), will be logarithmic as well, totaling in `O(logk)`

Thus, **the second is more efficient**.

Comment: I have a feeling that both approaches are equal with `O(n)`. Could you please take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12312488/538514?

Comment: @ViktorStolbin: no, it is `O(logn)` - I commented on your answer why.

Comment: @amit, Why is it `O(logn)` if you are going to need `logn` number of iterations with another `logn` number of searches for each `logn` iterations? Wouldn't that be `O(log^2(n))`?

Comment: @czchlong: The binary search is needed only after the last iteration, There is no point to search for a value until then, because it will not be in this range. The first i-1 iterations are simply checking if `x < arr[2^i]`, and if it is - advance to next iteration, without any binary search.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply binary search more or less directly with a small modification. This will roughly correspond to your Approach 2.

Basically, pick some number B and set A to 0, then check if the element you're looking for is between A and B. If it is, perform the usual kind of binary search in these boundaries, otherwise set B=A and A=2*A and repeat. This will take O(log(M)), where M is the position of the element you're looking for in the array.

Answer (score 3):

If the array is well-founded, i.e. has a smallest element (i.e. you have elements *x*<sub>0</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, ...), and all ele­ments are unique, then here's a simple approach: If you're looking for the number *n*, you can do a bi­na­ry search over the indices 0, ..., *n* − *x*<sub>0</sub>. Note that we always have the basic inequality *x*<sub>*i*</sub> ≥ *i* + *x*<sub>0</sub> for all *i* ≥ 0.

Thus you can find the value *n* in log<sub>2</sub>(*n* − *x*<sub>0</sub>) steps.

Comment: And with that upper limit in hand, the array in effect is no longer infinite, and the question becomes more like "which of the following modified binary searches is better?" (1) is (I think) obviously a stupid way to do a search since it's a hybrid linear-binary search dominated by the linear part. (2) might have something to say for it over a plain binary search: if your data is typically sparse (lots of missing elements) then you'd expect the bound to be a big over-estimate, and the target to be near the start, so for sufficiently sparse data (2) does fewer comparisons.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The crux of the question is that you don't have any *a priori* bounds on the runtime of the algorithm. The runtime depends on the value of the needle. But indeed, the only thing we can ask is *given a needle*, what's the most efficient way of finding it in the haystack?

Comment: True, but the value of the needle is bounded by the size of the non-infinite part of the input data, (2^N, N being the number of bits of input). So it's like any other complexity analysis, we just have to be clear what `n` means when we state `O(f(n))`. See also the confusion when someone says "fantastic news, they've proved that ISPRIME is in P", and someone else says, "what? Obviously it is, sqrt(n) trial divisions" ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, quite -- that's why I wish the OP had put a bit more care in phrasing the question and describing what he's after. :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop @KerrekSB: If you want to make it more interesting, assume an infinite sorted array with *real* numbers that have the non-zino property (for each `n` in `R`, there is finite index `i` such that `arr[i] > n`). I think with this modification the OPs second approach fits better.

Comment: @amit: so why's that called "non-zino"? I was trained a mathematician, so given that the array is sorted I call it "arr[i] -> infinity as i -> infinity". If the array is not sorted then it's some kind of lim-sup or lim-inf, but I don't remember the exact definition of that.

Comment: @SteveJessop: consider `f(x) = f(x-1) + 2^-x, f(0)=1` The "array" is monotonically increasing, but for each `x`, `f(x) < 2`. The non-zino property (I know it from the field of real time formal specification for systems) ensures there is progress. I believe it called non-Zeno over [Zenos paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)

Comment: @amit: FWIW the formal definition of "arr[i] -> infinity as i -> infinity" is "for each r a real number, there exists a finite index j such that for all k >= j, arr[k] > r". So together with sortedness, you see that it's equivalent. And thanks, I now understand why "non-Zeno": a "Zeno" sequence would be one that tends to a finite limit, and a "non-Zeno" doesn't. A sorted non-Zeno sequence -> ("tends to") infinity, but a non-sorted non-Zeno sequence doesn't necessarily tend to anything.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, of course. We are discussing strictly monotonically increasing sequences only. If this is the case - you don't have a known upper bound for the desired elements, but you have a finite sequence to reach it. I believe for this scenario - the OPs 2nd suggestion is a perfect match.

Comment: Better than (1) under most criteria, but I'd want a better definition of "good" before declaring it "perfect". For example, how would we be certain that the progression should be `2^N`, rather than e.g. `4^N`? I'm willing to believe it is, but the proof might not be trivial.

Comment: @SteveJessop: If we are only interested in big-O notation, it doesn't matter what is the base of the exponent. I don't think there is a simple way to assess the "best" base. Maybe something dynamic will do better..

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is infinite, the indexes are necessarily variable-length. That means that doing math on them is not `O(1)`, which in turn means that "binary search with first a search for an endpoint" has a slightly different time complexity than `O(log(k))`.

The index math done in the search for the endpoint is just a left shift by one, which takes `O(log(k))` because indexes up to `k` need up to `log(k)` bits and shifting left by one is linear in the number of bits.

The index math done in the binary search is all `O(log(k))` as well.

So the actual complexity of both algorithms is `O(log(k)^2)`. The complexity of a linear search would be `O(k log k)`, so it still loses.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents. We have an infinite array thus lets imagine that we are looking for very big number. Did you imagine? Well it's ever much more bigger. Note that length of interval to binary search in is `2^i = 2^(i+1)-2^i` thus it should take `log(2^i)=i` time to find the number. On the other hand it takes `i` time to reach the target interval. So the total time complexity is `O(n)` again. What I'm missing?

Comment: The second approach is `O(logn)`, where `n` is the *Index* of the desired element. Note that the binary search is indeed done in range `[2^i,2^(i+1)]` and thus `O(i)`, but `i` itself is `O(logn)`, because `2^(i+1) > n => i+1 > logn`, thus `O(i)` is actually `O(logn)`

Comment: Yeah, I was confused with `n` meaning. In other words my answer is the same `O(i)` where `i=logn`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.2010bit.com/searching-number-in-infinite-sorted-array-java/) is another implementation which use 2^n to search occurrence of element itself, and then gives this sub-array to binary search

```
e.g.
 arr = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1...........
 num = 8;

efficiency = 2logn
```

Answer (score 0):

--Complete Solution--  takes O(logn) time complexity

```java
public class B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Assuming sorted array of infinite length
        int a[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };

        int elementToFind = 12;

        int finalIndex = getFinalIndex(a, elementToFind);

        if (finalIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("Element not found");
        }
        System.out.println("Found element:" + a[finalIndex]);

    }

    private static int getFinalIndex(int[] a, int elementToFind) {

        int power = 2;
        int finalIndex = (int) Math.pow(2, power);

        for (int i = 0; i < finalIndex;) {

            if (elementToFind == a[finalIndex]) {
                return finalIndex;
            }

            else if (elementToFind < a[finalIndex]) {
                System.out.println("search through binary search algo");
                // taking i as starting index in binary search call
                int searchedIndex = callToBinarySearch(a, i, finalIndex);
                return searchedIndex;
            }

            else {
                i = finalIndex + 1;
                power = power * 2;
                finalIndex = (int) Math.pow(2, power);

            }
        }
        return -1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

package com.population.app;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Demo {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 17, 21, 45 };
    int index = findPos(arr, 45);
    if (index == -1)
        System.out.println("Element not found!");
    else
        System.out.println("Element found! index = " + index);
}

static int findPos(int arr[], int value) {
    int start = 0, end = 1;
    while (arr[end] < value) {
        start = end;
        end = 2 * end;
        // we know it is infinite but if it has finite elements it will reduce the
        // overflow of legth to n-1 element other wise the code will fail has array
        // index out of bound exception
        if (end > arr.length) {
            end = arr.length - 1;
        }
    }
    return binarySearch(arr, start, end, value);
}

static int binarySearch(int arr[], int start, int end, int ele) {
    if (end >= start) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        if (arr[mid] == ele)
            return mid;
        if (arr[mid] > ele)
            return binarySearch(arr, start, mid - 1, ele);
        return binarySearch(arr, mid + 1, end, ele);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

}