# find an element in infinite sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I got this as an interview question ...

infinite array which is sorted and from some position (we dont know the position) only  special symbol '$' will be there we need to find an element in that array ...

i gave a solution like get the first occurrance of  $ and then do binary search on the previous part from $

to find the first occurance of $ i gave solution like increment in window size if (i,2i)

the code i  gave is

```
#include<stdio.h>

int first(int *arr,int start,int end,int index)
{
    int mid=(start+end)/2;
    if((mid==start||arr[mid-1] != '$') && arr[mid]=='$')
        return mid;
    if(arr[mid]=='$')
        return first(arr,start,mid-1,index);
    else
    {
        if(arr[end] =='$')
            return first(arr,mid+1,end,index);
        else
            return first(arr,end+1,(1<<index),index+1);
    }
}

int binsearch(int *arr,int end ,int n)
{
    int low,high,mid;
    high=end-1;
    low=0;
    while(low<= high)
    {
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(n<arr[mid])
            high=mid-1;
        else if (n >arr[mid])
            low=mid+1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[20]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$','$'};
    int i =first(arr,0,2,2);
    printf("first occurance of $ is  %d\n",i);
    int n=20;//n is required element to be found
    if(i==0||arr[i-1]<n)
        printf(" element %d not  found",n);
    else{
        int p=binsearch(arr,i,n);
        if(p  != -1)
            printf("element %d is found at index %d",n,p);
        else
            printf(" element %d not found",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any better way to do the above problem ??

And also i wanted to know to find the first occurance of $ why should we move the window only in powers of 2 why not 3  like (i,3i)

Can someone pls through some light on the recurrance relation ..pls help..

Comment: The second part of the problem (after finding the $ sign) is related to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300904/find-an-element-in-an-infinite-length-sorted-array) [Note - it is not a dupe however, not voting to close or anything]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a fine way to do it to me.  As a small optimization, you can stop your `first` routine when you reach any number bigger than the one you're searching for (not just `$`).

Growing the window by powers of 2 means you'll find the end in `log_2(n)` iterations.  Growing by factors of 3 means you'll find it in `log_3(n)` iterations, which is smaller.  But not asymptotically smaller, as `O(log_2(n)) == O(log_3(n))`.  And your binary search is going to take `log_2(n)` steps anyway, so making the `first` part faster is not going to help your big-O running time.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient part of first function in iterative format would be

```
private int searchNum(int[] arr, int num, int start, int end) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = 1 << index) {
        if (start + i < arr.length) {
            if (arr[start] <= num && arr[start + i] >= num) {
                found = true;
                return bsearch(arr, num, start, start + i);
            } else {
                start = start + i;
            }
        } else {
            return bsearch(arr, num, start, arr.length - 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

this wont return you first occurance but instead try to find number directly as in your case you are missing probability that number itself could be found even before finding the $ symbol. So worst case complexity is O(logn)..
and best case would be (1)
after that you pass this to

```
private int bsearch(int[] array, int search, int first, int last) {
    int middle = (first + last) / 2;
    while (first <= last) {
        if (array[middle] < search)
            first = middle + 1;
        else if (array[middle] == search) {
            System.out.println(search + " found at location "
                    + (middle + 1) + ".");
            return middle;
        } else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last) / 2;
    }
    if (first > last)
        System.out.println(search + " is not present in the list.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

calling function

```
    if ((pos = searchNum(arr, num, 0, 2)) != -1) {
        System.out.println("found @ " + pos);
    } else {
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is python solution.

```
arr = [3,5,7,9,10,90,100,130,140,160,170,171,172,173,174,175,176]
elm = 171
k = 0
while (True):
    try:
        i = (1 << k) - 1 #  same as 2**k - 1 # eg 0,1,3,7,15
        # print k
        if(arr[i] == elm):
            print "found at " + str(i)
            exit()
        elif( arr[i] > elm):
            break                   

    except Exception as e:          
        break
    k = k+1

begin = 2**(k-1) # go back to previous power of 2
end = 2**k -1 

# Binary search
while (begin <= end):
    mid = begin + (end-begin)/2
    try:
        if(arr[mid] == elm):
            print "found at " + str(mid)
            exit()          
        elif(arr[mid] > elm):
            end = mid-1
        else:
            begin = mid+1

    except Exception as e:
        # Exception can occur if you are trying to access min element and that is not available. hence set end to mid-1
        end = mid-1


print "Element not found"
```