# Edge finding Binary Search

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Imagine a website that publishes the number of daily commuters in only a graphical form each day using a bar chart.  I want to determine the number by reading the bar chart after saving the graphic as an image (the image stuff is not important here).  The way I want to read the bar chart is by going to a pixel number (the #of commuters axis) and asking the question, "Is the pixel 'on' or 'off'?"  (On means that the bar is present and off means that this guess too high)  Note: that there is a lower bound of 0 and, technically, an infinite upper bound.  But, in reality, 10000 may be the realistic upper bound.  Also note, No Change from yesterday is a frequent finding.

Given a starting number from yesterday to guess, what's the most efficient way to find the number?  Efficient means fewest number of queries to ask if a pixel is on or off.

(To my non-CS eye, this seems like some-sort of edge-finding binary search, but without a pre-defined array.  I can say I've already learned a lot about searching.)

My algorithm follows as a function.  Any advice is most welcome.

```
def EdgeFind(BlackOrWhite,oldtrial,high,low):
# BlackOrWhite is a 0 or 1 depending on if the bar is present or not.  A 1 indicates that you are below or equal to the true number.  A 0 indicates that you are above the true number

# the initial values for oldtrial, high, and low all equal yesterday's value

 factorIncrease = 4#5
 finished = 0

 if BlackOrWhite == 1 and oldtrial==high:
    newtrial = oldtrial+factorIncrease*(high-low)+1
    high = newtrial
    low = oldtrial
 elif BlackOrWhite == 1 and high-oldtrial==1:
    finished = 1
    newtrial = oldtrial
 elif BlackOrWhite == 1:
    newtrial = oldtrial+(high-oldtrial)/2
    low = oldtrial

 if BlackOrWhite == 0 and oldtrial==low:
    newtrial = (oldtrial)/2
    high = oldtrial
    low = newtrial
 elif BlackOrWhite == 0 and oldtrial-low==1:
    finished = 1
    newtrial = oldtrial-1
 elif BlackOrWhite == 0:
    newtrial = oldtrial-(oldtrial-low+1)/2
    high = oldtrial

 if (oldtrial==1) and low!=1:
    finished = 1

 return finished,newtrial,high,low
```

Comment: What is the question? If you want your code reviewed - please post it in [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If your algorithm fails - please mention it. If it is something else, please be direct and say what it is

Comment: My question is, What's the best way to find what I am calling an edge?  Any guidance is appreciated.  (My code works fine, but I don't know if it's the most efficient algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Calling an edge can indeed be done with a modified binary search.

It is similar to this question: [Find an element in an infinite length sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12300904/572670).

Let the searched index be `idx`

Given the value of yesterday - you need to find the "edge", doing so can be found with increasing/decreasing the idx exponentially.

For example, if yesterday was 1000, you will search in `1000,1001,1002,1004,1008,1016,1032,...` Until you find that the pixel changed the switch in the color.

Let's say you found it in iteration `i`, that means that the searched edge is somewhere in the range: `[1000 + 2^(i-1), 1000 + 2^i]`. (of course the same applies for down instead of up with `[1000 - 2^(i-1), 1000 - 2^i]`.

Now, you have a classic binary search problem in this range.

Complexity remains `O(logN)`, where `N` is the height of the change since yesterday.

Comment: Thanks.  This gives me something to think about.  Much appreciated.